# AutoFac System.InvalidOperationException: Server could not create ASP.frmpaymentadd_aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, autofac, .net-4.7.2

I am working on a legacy solution that is relatively fragile and I am looking to introduce AutoFac so that I can introduce unit tests and also inject various things such as Serilog.ILogger.

This is whats in my web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <!-- This module handles disposal of the request lifetime scope. -->
        <add name="ContainerDisposal" type="Autofac.Integration.Web.ContainerDisposalModule, Autofac.Integration.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        <!-- This module injects properties on web forms. You could also use the UnsetPropertyInjectionModule or a custom module. -->
        <add name="PropertyInjection" type="Autofac.Integration.Web.Forms.PropertyInjectionModule, Autofac.Integration.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

I am registering AutoFac in Global.ascx.cs as per the below code block

```
private void AutofacRegister()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

           
    builder.Register<Serilog.ILogger>((c, p) =>
    {
        return new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
            .Enrich.WithMachineName()
            .CreateLogger();
    }).SingleInstance();

    //Set Dependent Parser
    _containerProvider = new ContainerProvider(builder.Build());
}
```

I am trying to introduce basic logging into one of the pages

```
public partial class frmPaymentAdd : _SmartPayPage
{
    private readonly ILogger _Logger;

    public frmPaymentAdd(ILogger logger)
    {
        _Logger = logger;
    }
    
    .....
}
```

Everything compiles and runs but when I navigate to the respective page I get the following error

> at __ASP.FastObjectFactory_app_web_usuz0hix.Create_ASP_frmpaymentadd_aspx()
> at System.Web.Compilation.BuildResultCompiledType.CreateInstance()
> at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
> at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
> at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String virtualPath, String path)
> at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
> at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
> at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

I would be grateful if someone could help point me in the right direction of what I need to do, or what I have missed in order to get this running.

Thanks

Simon

Answer (score 0):

Autofac for web forms only injects properties, not constructors. Make the constructor on your form take zero parameters and make the logger a get/set property. [There is a working example here.](https://github.com/autofac/Examples/tree/master/src/WebFormsExample)

Aside: I didn't see you post the Global.asax part of the code where you implemented `IContainerProviderAccessor`. I assume you have that part done since you're setting `_containerProvider` in the code you showed, but since you didn't actually show the rest I can't be sure. Make sure you have that part, too, or the property injection won't work.

Comment: Ive seen that working example, Ive created a brand new application from that working example, and even used that working example and when following that. I get an object is not an instance of an object error.

Comment: If you're following the example - parameterless constructor on web forms, get/set properties on web forms for injection, `IContainerProviderAccessor` - then the problem likely isn't in the Autofac integration, it's elsewhere. The exception you posted has the stack trace but not the actual _message_ so there's nothing else here anyone can go on to help. Sorry.

Comment: Well, I guess the message is in the title of the question - InvalidOperationException - but it sounds like you're getting a new/different error now, so... still not enough here to go on.